# What does Windows 7 'Diagnose Network' actually do (as opposed to "just check")?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, virtualbox, samba

I have a Linux guest virtual machine under VirtualBox, on Windows 7 Professional, which exports its disk as a Samba share.

When I connect to `\\SHARENAME` after booting, though, while the share does appear, and the files are there, they are greyed out with a fat grey "X" overlaid. If I click on any of them (file or folder), I'm informed that *the item is not available* and Windows suggests I run a Diagnose Network.

If I choose **not** to, and cancel, nothing happens; the share remains unavailable for up to ten minutes, after which it'll stabilize and start working for no apparent reason. During this ungrace time, connecting to the IP address, restarting Samba, twiddling with NET.EXE from command line, etc., all avail nothing.

If I accept, the Diagnose Network applet starts (d’oh), and after four or five seconds it reports that **nothing is wrong**. And it's right: because just an instant before it terminates, *the icons become fully visible and the X overlay disappears*. Nothing's wrong, *but that's because it just got fixed*!

So I deduce that Windows Diagnostics does *something* without even being aware it's doing it, to the point that it uncharacteristically doesn't even boast of having solved anything.

I'd therefore very much like to be able to run this something, whatever it is, directly from a shell script, instead of having to run the tiresome connect-doesntwork!-wannadiagnose?-yesdamnyoureyes-nothingwrongyouninny gauntlet. Or having to wait ten minutes before being able to do anything.

But what *is* it that Windows Diagnostics *fixes*, rather than just *diagnosing*?

Or equivalently, is there a way of making the share become "available", whatever this means?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/471743/what-does-fix-network-problems-actually-do) lists what Windows Diagnostics claims to be doing, but that's not what I want. The official Microsoft answer states,

> The following table contains a list of issues that the Fix My Network
>   Wizard can check for and fix. The list is not exhaustive, and there
>   are many more issues that the wizard can fix

While not claiming it's a complete list (rather, stating the contrary), the problem here is that Fix My Network can't be **just checking** things, it must be **actively doing** something, even when it doesn't say so.

More to the point, I've tried *checking* those same things that appear in MS's list. My checking has had no effect.

Following the advice of [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/305911/how-to-make-windows-7-network-show-samba-share-after-vm-is-rebooted-restored), I've tried the "running `nbtstat -R` to purge and reload the name cache" thing, with no results.

## Update (and fix)

Following @DanielB's hint, I was able to fix everything by disabling Offline Availability that I must have turned on somehow on the VM's share.

My guess is that O.A. is checking every ten minutes whether the files are there or not; that if they are not, the disk is shown as unavailable, even if it meanwhile it's become available; and that Fix My Network somehow teases the check into running immediately.

So probably tinkering with Offline Availability would also have fixed my problem. This can be useful to someone with the need for O.A.; I did not have such need, so I just disabled O.A. altogether and the share now comes up at once.

Comment: The gray X overlay is probably part of the offline availability feature. The virtual machine is hosted on the same PC where the network share is mounted, right?

Comment: Hi @DanielB, definitely yes. Somehow the Samba share was included in the offline files, and the synchronisation seems to happen in the background and require a long time. Network Diagnose unblocks it (so does, indeed, checking offline availability). But since I had no need for offline availability, I disabled it, and -- problem solved.

Comment: @DanielB -  you're more than welcome to copy the fix as an answer of your own, if this question gets reopened.

Comment: I’ll pass, thanks. :D Before you post that fix as an answer, you’ll have to reword the question not to be about the troubleshooting wizard but the actual problem.